# Capture text from a column in another worksheet - Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, function, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I am trying to capture text from a column in another worksheet.

For example:
In *Column Y* in **Worksheet1** - I want to capture the texts in the cells (lets say there are 10 cells with texts out of 30) but miss off the title cell in Y3.

Then I want to display these captured texts in cell *L3* in **Worksheet2** with text from each cell on a new line within L3.

Is there a way to do this? Will I need to complete this using an array?

Many thanks

Comment: @pnuts excel 2013

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula then select `Wrap Text`. See the screenshot below. If it serve your purpose then you can implement for `Sheet2`.

```
=D4 & CHAR(10) & D5 & CHAR(10) & D6 & CHAR(10) & D7
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this - but I think I may have confused you. I would like to have the formula dynamic (e.g. D:D) and by that I mean there is possibly 100 rows of data but we are only interested in Column D for example. Column D will be a mixture of blank cells, cells with text and numbers and cells with #N/A. In a different worksheet, I would like a cell to capture only the text and numbers in the cells in Column D and if possible display every 'record' in a different line within the same cell

Comment: @K.Honda Got your point. It is difficult to do that in same cell but easier to get text and number in cells one by one. Otherwise `VBA` required.

Comment: @Harun24HR what will be the way to display it in cells one by one?

Comment: @K.Honda In case of error cells like `N/A` only way to use a helper `(an extra column for tricks purpose)` column. If there is no error values then we can use array formula to do that.

Comment: @Harun24HR Do you have an example that I can look at please?